# Test within new command - xstring package

Tags: overleaf, xstring

I am trying to create a new command, to test wether another command ends with the string "...s\xspace" or "...\xspace", where the dots are other characters than s.

I've found that the package xstring lets me test for this, and thus I have come up with the test
`\IfEndWith{\sub}{s\xspace}{\sub'}{\sub's}` where "\sub" is my own command, returning a specified name, that sometimes change. (Could be "Lucas" or "John"). This test seems to work as intended.

If the \sub-command returns "Lucas", I would like the new command to return "Lucas'" (with an apostrophe). If the \sub-command returns "John", I would like the new command to return "John's".

For the new command, I have created this:

```
\newcommand{\subpos}{%
  \IfEndWith{\sub}{s\xspace}{\sub'\xspace}{\sub's\xspace}%
}
```

But it fails to compile and I think it wants me to create a "Iffalse" statement, which I would think was incorporated into the "IfEndWith" test?

How can i change my new command to make it work?

Let me know if I should have provided an MWE or any other information that could help.

Comment: Imagine that you see this question and want to try to answer it. Would you like an MWE to test the code and see the exact error message?

Comment: Well if you are familiar with the xstring package and used to create new commands, you might be able to answer it without an MWE, as this is quite possibly my understanding of the package that is off. (which actually was the case, as further reading lead to the conclusion that the package has incorporated \fullexpandarg by deafult, which I regulated to \expandarg, and thus solved the problem) 

But I understand your argument. And thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: Imagine you are the author of xstring and familiar with the package. Would you prefer to answer a question with a MWE that you can test or one where you have to waste your time to write a testfile first (and guess if is really correct)?